# Does the word 'inherent' in right position in the clause "The dangers inherent in bicycle riding "?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

Because the word *'inherent'* is an adjective, is it in right place in the clause

> "The dangers inherent in bicycle riding"?

I think it should be "*inherent dangers*" because it's an adjective.

Comment: No. ' ... inherent in bicycle riding' is coherent. Compare ' ... the toxins present in cigarette smoke'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh I see! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You would use "inherent dangers with 'of' for instance "...the inherent dangers of bicycle riding". In the "dangers inherent in" _inherent_ is acting as a verb (it's like _contained_ in "The items contained in that box") but in "inherent dangers of" _inherent_ is acting as an adjective modifying _dangers_ (it's more like _valuable_ in "The valuable items in that box")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative pronoun and the verb have simply been omitted.
"The dangers (which/that are) inherent in bicycle riding."